# Changing Spinner Highlight AND line color

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, spinner

This XML below results in my Spinner having an orange line across the bottom and an orange rectangle on the right-hand side. I have two questions:

1. How can I make it so that the orange rectangle on the right-hand side is an orange triangle, like the default one associated with Theme.Dialog?
2. Now that I changed the look of the Spinner, when I click on it it no longer gets highlighted. I want to make it look the way I want AND highlight to a lighter color of orange when I press on it.

Do I have to accomplish both things in the same XML file? I've already got the drawable below set to the background of my spinner, so I can't declare the background twice right?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

My Drawable Custom Spinner Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
  <shape >
      <solid android:color="@color/base_orange" />
  </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item android:bottom="1.0dp"
  android:left="0.0dp"
  android:right="10.0dp">
  <shape >
      <solid android:color="@color/white" />
  </shape>
</item>


<item android:bottom="25.0dp">
  <shape >
      <solid android:color="@color/base_orange" />
  </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to [this](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and get the spinner drawables according to your wish.

Hope that helps